# Probability Distribution $Z=X^2 +Y^2$ from joint PDF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

The following is Solved Problem $4.31$ from Schuam's Probability, Random Variables and Random Processes

Let X and Y be two r.v's with join pdf $f_{XY}(x,y)$. Let $Z = X^2+Y^2$ find $f_{Z}(z)$

$$F_{Z}(z) = \int_{-\sqrt{z}}^{\sqrt{z}}\int_{-\sqrt{z-y^{2}}}^{\sqrt{z - y^{2}}} f_{XY}(x,y)\hspace{1mm}dx\hspace{1mm}dy$$

and

**Step 1:**
$$f_{z}(z)=\frac{F_{Z}(z)}{dz} = \int_{-\sqrt{z}}^{\sqrt{z}}
\hspace{2mm}[\hspace{2mm} \frac{\partial}{\partial z}  \int_{-\sqrt{z-y^{2}}}^{\sqrt{z - y^{2}}} f_{XY}(x,y)\hspace{1mm}dx]\hspace{1mm}dy $$

**Step 2:**
$$= \int_{-\sqrt{z}}^{\sqrt{z}}
\hspace{2mm}[\hspace{2mm} \frac{\partial}{\partial z} 
\int_{0}^{\sqrt{z - y^{2}}} f_{XY}(x,y)\hspace{1mm}dx - \int_{0}^{-\sqrt{z - y^{2}}} f_{XY}(x,y)\hspace{1mm}dx]\hspace{1mm}dy $$

**Step 3:**
$$= \int_{-\sqrt{z}}^{\sqrt{z}}\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{z-y^{2}}} \hspace{1mm}[\hspace{1mm} f_{XY}(\sqrt{z-y^2},y)+f_{XY}(-\sqrt{z-y^2},y) \hspace{1mm}] \hspace{1mm}
dy$$

I don't understand Step $1$. I understand that in Step $3$ they are using Leibniz integral rule, but I don't understand how in Step $1$ they can just move the $\frac{d}{dz}$ inside the first integral because the limits of integration are a function of $z$.

Could someone please elaborate and explain Step $1$ to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$h(y,z) =\int_{-\sqrt{z-y^{2}}}^{\sqrt{z - y^{2}}} f_{XY}(x,y)\hspace{1mm}dx$$

Then we have $h(\sqrt{z},z)=h(-\sqrt{z},z)=0$ and using the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) we obtain

$$f_{z}(z)=\frac{F_{Z}(z)}{dz} = \frac{d}{dz}\int_{-\sqrt{z}}^{\sqrt{z}}
\hspace{2mm}h(y,z)dy $$
$$=h(\sqrt{z},z)\frac{1}{2\sqrt{z}}+h(-\sqrt{z},z)\frac{1}{2\sqrt{z}}+\int_{-\sqrt{z}}^{\sqrt{z}}\frac{\partial }{\partial z}h(y,z)dy$$
$$=\int_{-\sqrt{z}}^{\sqrt{z}}
\hspace{2mm}\left[\hspace{2mm} \frac{\partial}{\partial z}  \int_{-\sqrt{z-y^{2}}}^{\sqrt{z - y^{2}}} f_{XY}(x,y)\hspace{1mm}dx\right]\hspace{1mm}dy$$

Comment: Why can you simply make the second integral into a function h(y,z)? Is it because the integral is over the variable x so as far as the the operation of integration is concerned z and y are simply parameters?

Comment: Yes, we are integrating over $x$ only for the inside integral, so we will obtain a function of $y$ and $z$.